# query orders by date AND time in craft commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, datetime

How can I query all completed orders within the last hour? It seems craft is only comparing a date by `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Following query collects all orders from the same day, as `{{dateFrom}}` would output `2017-10-13` and not eg. `2017-10-13 11:22:08`

```
{% set dateFrom = now|date_modify('-3600 seconds') %}
{% for order in craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered( '>= ' ~ dateFrom) %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

adding something like 
`craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered( '>= ' ~ dateFrom|date('c'))` would find any orders at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'>= ' ~ dateFrom|date('c')
```

is correct to output the DateTime object as a string with the time (and timezone) included. If you don’t use the filter it’s output in the `Y-m-d` format by default.

So my recommendation would be to double check what `dateFrom|date('c')` actually outputs and to compare it with the `dateOrdered` values in the CP or database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, of course `'>= ' ~ dateFrom|date('c')` works perfectly fine.. I didn't get any output before, because (i think) the database time is UTC and  crafts dates are UTC+2. So I ended up taking the offset into account by doing this:
`{% set dateFrom = now|date_modify( ((now|date("Z") + 3600)  * (-1)) ~' seconds') %}` and `.dateOrdered( '>= ' ~ dateFrom|date('c'))`

Comment: Something isn’t right, you should not need to factor in any timezone differences.

Comment: sry, for my late reply. there is indeed something odd going on between our DB and craft - but as this behavior only occurs on the dev-environment I am just going to ignore this for now. Anyways, the original question was answered perfectly! thx alot.